# asp.net mongodb docker System.TimeoutException

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, docker, sockets, microservices

I'm new to docker and microservices. Getting this timeout exception:

> System.TimeoutException: 'A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/localhost:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/localhost:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
> ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address [::1]:27017
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.Connect(Socket socket, EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStream(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.Heartbeat(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2022-10-07T14:01:55.8910217Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2022-10-07T14:01:55.8910224Z" }] }.'

docker-compose

```
    version: '3.4'
    
    services:
      catalogdb:
        image: mongo
    
      catalog.api:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}catalogapi
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Services\Catalog\Catalog.API\Dockerfile
    
    volumes:
      mongo_data:
```

docker-compose.override

```
    version: '3.4'
    
    services:
      catalogdb:
        container_name: catalogdb
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        volumes:
            - mongo_data:/data/db
    
      catalog.api:
        container_name: catalog.api
        environment:
          - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
          - "DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString=mongodb://catalogdb:27017"
        depends_on:
          - catalogdb
        ports:
          - "8000:80"
```

appsettings.json

```
    {
      "DatabaseSettings": {
        "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
        "DatabaseName": "ProductDb",
        "CollectionName": "Products"
      },
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*"
    }
```

I've tried so far:

1. Adding exceptions to the Firewall
2. Turn down antivirus
3. Checked that containers run on the same network
   [image]
4. Adding **command: ["mongod", "--port", "27017"]** line to catalogdb config
5. Putting catalogdb instead of localhost in the appsettings file - same error

Please help! It's so devastating when you face the critical problem at the beginning of learning and can't solve it

Comment: Hi @ProgBlogger , please check my repository which is working fine for the same. https://github.com/Jeevananthan-23/AspDotNetMicroservices/tree/main/src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API

Comment: @JeevananthanS Thanks. Tried it out and has the same timeout exceptions. Seems that the issue is in my environment

Comment: So still you have problem ?

Comment: @JeevananthanS yes

Comment: Have you sorted it ? What was the solution ?

Comment: @Illep I didn't find an appropriate solution. The thing is that I was going through a video course of building microservices apps. But I've been using asp.net 6 meanwhile in the video course it was used the asp.net 5. So I installed the VS 2019 and went exact steps from the video. And it worked

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and I solved it by changing the connection string in the appsettings from localhost to the name of my container (mongodb in my case) :

```
"ConnectionString": "mongodb://mongodb:27017"
```

Furthermore, the connection string was cached within the local volumes so I had to clear and restart my docker images

- docker volume prune
- docker-compose build
- docker-compose up